# symfony 4 with fixtures, the getReference method does not return the expected object (return PROXY/__CG__/... instead an instance of User class)

Tags: symfony, symfony4

From symfony 4, I created two fixtures classes. 
When I run the command "./bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load" I get this error :

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Article::setAuthor() must be an instance of User, instance of Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User given, called in /home/okli/PhpstormProjects/nomads_fiction/src/DataFixtures/ArticleFixtures.php on line 53
```

From the fixture 1 (the first fixture called), I created a user with this code :

```
$myuser = new User();
$myuser->setName("foo");
...

$em->persist($myuser);
$em->persist();

$this->addReference("foo", $myuser);
$this->log->info("class is : " . get_class($myuser)); //  print "class is : App\Entity\User" its good !
```

From the fixture 2, I loaded the myuser object like this :

```
$myuser = $this->getReference("foo");
$this->log->info("class is : " . get_class($myuser)); //  print "class is : Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User", why not App\Entity\User ?
```

Why getReference doesn't return me the exact same object I returned from the fixture 1 ? Where is my mistake ?

Thank you for some help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what it was supposed to do. The getReference() function lets you obtain a reference to an entity for which the identifier is known, without loading that entity from the database, which is a proxy object of the generated class for the User. Full documentation [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies)

In fact, doctrine doesn't really care if you use a proxy object. All you have to do to get your code working is to remove the type-hinting from the setAuthor function in Article entity (i.e setAuthor(User $user) to setAuthor($user)).

This will work because all you want to achieve by calling the setAuthor function is to establish an association to an entity. Since you already have the identifier for this entity, you don't have to fully load it.

**EDIT:** As Matías Navarro Carter observed, entity proxy classes extend real entity classes, so the type-hinting should work anyway. I guess you forgot to use the appropriate namespace in your Article entity. Maybe you are missing something like this in your Article.php:

```
use App\Entity\User;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if removing the typehinting will be of any help, because AFAIK Doctrine proxies extend your entity class. In fact, it can lead to bugs. There must be something else missing there.

Comment: You are right that proxy objects extend entity classes.